# What use is there for defining magic methods outside of a class?

Tags: python, string, class, module, magic-methods

What happens if I define a magic method outside a class?
For example, say I do:

```
def __str__(stuff):
    return "chicken"
```

directly inside the module.

When would something like this be useful? I thought it might be useful if I `import` this module named `module1` elsewhere and try to do `print(module1)`, but that just prints out the file location and other stuff.

So is there even any use for using a magic method outside a class? Is it even really a magic method any more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment (Python 3.9), two module-level magic methods can be defined: `__getattr__` and `__dir__` (see [PEP 562](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/) for details).

- `__getattr__` overrides attribute access on that module, including imports of the form `from x import y`.
- `__dir__` overrides what is returned by `dir(module)`.

For example:

```py
# foo.py

def __getattr__(name):
    return name

def __dir__():
    return ['foo', 'bar']
```

Then we can use it in the following way:

```py
>>> import foo
>>> dir(foo)
['bar', 'foo']
>>> from foo import bar
>>> bar
'bar'
```